# Looping with distance matching

Tags: stata

I want to match treated firms to control firms by industry and year considering firms that are the closest in terms of profitability (roa). I want a `1:1` match. I am using a distance measure (`mahalanobis`).

I have `530,000` firm-year observations in my sample, namely `267,000` treated observations and `263,000` control observations approximatively. Here is my code:

```
gen neighbor1 = .
gen idobs = .

levelsof industry 
local a = r(levels)

levelsof year
local b = r(levels)

foreach i in `a' {  
foreach j in `b'{    
capture noisily psmatch2 treat if industry == `i' & year == `j', mahalanobis(roa) 
capture noisily replace neighbor1 = _n1 if industry == `i' & year == `j' 
capture noisily replace idobs = _id if industry == `i' & year == `j'
drop _treated _support _weight _id _n1 _nn  
}  
}
```

`Treat` is my treatment variable. It takes the value of `1` for treated observations and `0` for non-treated observations.

The command `psmatch2` creates the variable `_n1` and `_id` among others. `_n1` is the id number of the matched observation (closest neighbor) and `_id` is an id number (`1` - `530,000`) that is unique to each observation.

The code 'works', i.e. I get no error message. My variable `neighbor1` has `290,724` non-missing observations.

However, these `290,724` observations vary between `1` and `933` which is odd. The variable `neighbor1` should provide me the observation id number of the matched observation, which can vary between `1` and `530,000`.

It seems that the code erases or ignores the result of the matching process in different subgroups. What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit:

*I found a public dataset and adapted my previous code so that you can run my code with this dataset and see more clearly what the problem could be.*

I am using Vella and Verbeek (1998) panel data on `545` men worked every year from `1980`-`1987` from this website: https://www.stata.com/texts/eacsap/

Let's say that I want to match treated observations, i.e. people, to control observations by marriage status (`married`) and year considering people that worked a similar number of hours (`hours`), i.e. the shortest distance.

I create a random treatment variable (`treat`) for the sake of this example.

```
use http://www.stata.com/data/jwooldridge/eacsap/wagepan.dta

gen treat = round(runiform())

gen neighbor1 = .
gen idobs = .

levelsof married 
local a = r(levels)

levelsof year 
local b = r(levels)

foreach i in `a' {
foreach j in `b'{
  capture noisily psmatch2 treat if married == `i' & year == `j', mahalanobis(hours) 
  capture noisily replace neighbor1 = _n1 if married == `i' & year == `j'
  capture noisily replace idobs = _id if married == `i' & year == `j'
  drop _treated _support _weight _id _n1 _nn
}
}
```

What this code should do is to look at each subgroup of observations: `444` observations in `1980` that are not married, `101` observations in `1980` that are married, ..., and `335` observations in `1987` that are married. In each of these subgroups, I would like to match a treated observation to a control observation considering the shortest distance in the number of hours worked.

There are two problems that I see after running the code.

First, the variable `idobs` should take a unique number between `1` and `4360` because there are `4360` observations in this dataset. It is just an ID number. It is not the case. A few observations can have an ID number `1`, `2` and so on.

Second,  `neighbor1` varies between `1` and `204` meaning that the matched observations have only ID numbers varying from `1` to `204`.

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: Are you sampling with or without replacement? Wouldn't you expect some firms to be discarded if they are not a good match for your treated firms? Did you forget to sort by id?

Comment: My guess is that  you want something like `sort _id` followed by `replace idobs = firm_id[_n1]`.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I agree that it would be better for you to have some data with you to see what the problem is. How can I link a dataset to this post?

Comment: If the dataset is not proprietary, you could post a link to a github repo. Perhaps even better would be if you can replicate the problem using one of Stata's publicly available [webuse test datasets](https://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/r.html).

Comment: I see. Thank you! I will explore if I couldn't use one of these datasets.

Comment: Use the `dataex` command. See the Stata tag wiki on here for more info.

Comment: @PearlySpencer I added an edit to this post using a public dataset. Please let me know if you need something else. I hope that this edit will clarify the problem with my code vs. what I want it to do.

Comment: Does it need to be a mahalanobis matching? It seems to me as that is most useful if you match one multiple variables, but you seem to be matching on a single variable. Also, do you only want the matching or do you also need the ATT? If you only want the matching, and if regular nearest neighbor matching is fine, then I have a solution that does not use `psmatch2`. If you need to use `psmatch2` then your issue is related to the fact that `psmatch2` re-use the same IDs in each subgroup. And the missing values comes from your code not doing a`1:1` match

Comment: You have a good point. I don't need the Mahalanobis matching. I just want the matching, I don't need the ATT. I am interested in the nearest neighbor matching. I don't need to use `psmatch2` if it is not necessary. I thought that `psmatch2` was the right command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using the command `iematch`, installed through the package `ietoolkit` -> `ssc install ietoolkit`. For disclosure, I wrote this command. `psmatch2` is great if you want the ATT. But if all you want is to match observations across two groups using nearest neighbor, then `iematch` is cleaner.

In both commands you need to make each industry-year match in a subset, then combine that information. In both commands the matched group ID will restart from 1 in each subset.

Using your example data, this creates one matchID var for each subset, then you will have to find a way to combine these to a single matchID without conflicts across the data set.

```
* use data set and keep only vars required for simplicity
use http://www.stata.com/data/jwooldridge/eacsap/wagepan.dta, clear
keep year married hour

* Set seed for replicability. NEVER use the 123456 seed in production, randomize a new seed
set seed 123456

*Generate mock treatment
gen treat = round(runiform())

*generate vars to store results
gen matchResult = .
gen matchDiff = .
gen matchCount = .

*Create locals for loops
levelsof married 
local married_statuses = r(levels)

levelsof year 
local years = r(levels)

*Loop over each subgroup
foreach year of local years {
    foreach married_status of local married_statuses {
        *This command is similar to psmatch2, but a simplified version for 
        * when you are not looking for the ATT. 
        * This command is only about matching.
        iematch if married == `married_status' & year == `year', grp(treat) match(hour) seedok m1 maxmatch(1)
      
        *These variables list meta info about the match. See helpfile for docs,
        *but this copy info from each subset in this loop to single vars for 
        *the full data set. Then the loop specfic vars are dropped
        replace matchResult     = _matchResult  if married == `married_status' & year == `year'
        replace matchDiff   = _matchDiff    if married == `married_status' & year == `year'
        replace matchCount  = _matchCount   if married == `married_status' & year == `year'
        drop _matchResult _matchDiff _matchCount
      
        *For each loop you will get a match ID restarting at 1 for each loop. 
        *Therefore we need to save them in one var for each loop and combine afterwards.
        rename _matchID matchID_`married_status'_`year'
    }
}
```